# nl2br() function ads <br> if no character is entered after/in the next line

Tags: php, html

I am using nl2br function with str_replace as follows:

```
$data = (!empty($_POST['content']))?nl2br($_POST['content']):null;
$data_fix = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $data);
```

When I insert data into database next lines automatically receives a `<br>`. Okay fine. To 95% extent this is what I want. But if there is no character entered after the next line in `<textarea>` it still enters a `<br>`.

Example:

What I want:

```
Hello Stackoverflow!<br>I am new here.
(new line space eliminated)
```

What I get:

```
Hellow Stactoverflow!<br>I am new here.<br>
(new line space inserted)
```

Please help me solve this!

Comment: use [trim](http://php.net/trim) before nl2br to remove whitespace (spaces/newlines) off the beginning/end of a string.

Comment: or do the nl2br AFTER you do the str_replace. There's **NO** point in looking for a `\r` after they've all been replaced with `<br>` in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps you should investigate why you're putting a newline at the end of the string in the first place? Use a function like `implode()` to put newlines between strings when building from an array, instead of appending a newline to each line.

Comment: @MarcB That seems to be a totally different issue, and won't cause the trailing `<br>` that he's complaining about.

Comment: before or after? confused... @Jonathan Kuhn

Comment: @Barmar: it's probably added client-side BEFORE the form's submitted.

Comment: @MarcB If you did the nl2br after the str_replace, there wouldn't be any `nl` to `br`. Also, nl2br doesn't replace the newlines, it inserts a br before a newline meaning that they still exist in the string.

Comment: fixed.. trim did the job.. but after the nl2br()..

Comment: `nl2br(trim($_POST['content']))` is what you want. When I say "before", I don't mean physically in the string before nl2br. But in the way I put here, nesting the trim call inside of nl2br, trim will be called first and the returned value from that will be passed to nl2br. Meaning that trim was called *before* nl2br. This sort of confusion is why it is usually better to not nest function calls as breaking this into 3 lines, one to get the value from post and one for each function call is a lot more clear.

Comment: I answered my own question for future reference to other people who have same problem! Thanks @JonathanKuhn.. You helped buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

trim() function will prevent adding extra `<br>` which are not needed if there is no text entered in or after the next line!

Simply replaced

```
$data = (!empty($_POST['content']))?nl2br($_POST['content']):null;
```

With

```
$data = (!empty($_POST['content']))?nl2br(trim($_POST['content'])):null;
```

And it did the job! But trim() should be after the nl2br() otherwise it won't work!

Answered my own question for future reference of other people seeking solution to the same!